# Procedure of minifying css files and java script files

Tags: css

How to minify the css files and what is the procedure of minifying css files and minimisation of java script file

Comment: At SO, we don't do "how-tos". You need to ask a specific question, which can have a specific answer, that could help others as well as yourself. Alongside the question you need to provide what you've tried that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question so I'll answer what I understood :

To minimify CSS, you can use [CSS Minifier](https://cssminifier.com/) and for JavaScript, [JSCompress](https://jscompress.com/).

Hope this helps